# add space to batch file

Tags: batch

How my bath file can process space in path example:

C:\Documents and Settings\K\Desktop\New Folder

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0"
IF EXIST "%1" GOTO DECODE_INDIVIDUAL

:DECODE_MULTIPLE
xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y "%cd%\encoded" "%cd%\decoded\"
dir %cd%\decoded\*.php  /A:-D /B /O:N /S >> %cd%\filelist.txt

@echo on
for /F %%e in (%cd%\filelist.txt) do ( copy "%%e" "bin\file.php" && "php.exe" "bin\decoder.php" "bin\file.php" && move "bin\file.php" "%%e" && del "bin\file.php")
del /Q "%cd%\filelist.txt"
GOTO DECODE_END

:DECODE_INDIVIDUAL
@echo on
"php.exe" "%cd%\bin\decoder.php" "%1"

:DECODE_END
```

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

CMD doesn’t like spaces in directories so use quote your path as below:

“C:\Documents and Settings\K\Desktop\New Folder”

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\K\Desktop\DECODER>for /F %e in ("C:\Documents and Sett
ings\K\Desktop\DECODER\filelist.txt") do (copy "%e" "bin\file.php"   && "php.exe
" "bin\phplockit_decoder.php" "bin\file.php"   && move "bin\file.php" "%e"   &&
del "bin\file.php" )

C:\Documents and Settings\K\Desktop\DECODER>(copy "C:\Documents" "bin\file.php"
  && "php.exe" "bin\phplockit_decoder.php" "bin\file.php"   && move "bin\file.ph
p" "C:\Documents"   && del "bin\file.php" )
        1 file(s) copied.

Answer (score 1):

I added quotes around a few file path locations... this should work:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0"
IF EXIST "%1" GOTO DECODE_INDIVIDUAL

:DECODE_MULTIPLE
xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y "%cd%\encoded" "%cd%\decoded\"
dir "%cd%\decoded\*.php"  /A:-D /B /O:N /S >> "%cd%\filelist.txt"

@echo on
for /F "tokens=*" %%e in ("%cd%\filelist.txt") do ( copy "%%e" ".\bin\file.php" && "php.exe" ".\bin\decoder.php" ".\bin\file.php" && move ".\bin\file.php" "%%e" && del ".\bin\file.php")
del /Q "%cd%\filelist.txt"
GOTO DECODE_END

:DECODE_INDIVIDUAL
@echo on
"php.exe" "%cd%\bin\decoder.php" "%1"

:DECODE_END
```

Comment: don't work <br>bin\file.php: errorCould Not Find C:\Documents and Settings\K\Desktop\DECODE
R\bin\file.php

Comment: try it now.  I added some base directory ".\" references...

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\K\Desktop\DECODER>(copy "C:\Documents" ".\bin\file.php
"   && "php.exe" ".\bin\decoder.php" ".\bin\file.php"   && move ".\bin
\file.php" "C:\Documents"   && del ".\bin\file.php" )

The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: How about now?  I added a tokens option to the for statement.

Comment: <br>.\bin\file.php: errorCould Not Find C:\Documents and Settings\K\Desktop\DECODER\bin\file.php